# Are answers involving generalizations of previous answers accepted?

Tags: support

Basically wish to know the general consensus on the above.

I wish to post a generalization of a pretty famous integral result as an answer to an answer discussing that integral result.

Comment: I think its fine; its more like you're writing an appendix, don't expect to become the accepted answer

Comment: I think it depends. I like answers which are "big picture" answers, linking the question to other, interesting, deeper stuff. But they should always make some sort of attempt to actually answer the question...(so e.g. illustrating how the more general thing can be solved would be good).

Comment: related https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33136/posting-generalizations-of-already-asked-questions